# Как упаковать таблицу dbf в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Я удаляю данные из таблицы и хочу упаковать таблицу через Pack Table но все время выходит ошибка не может открыть таблицу

```
 procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
 var text1,text,mes,god,data,nf:string;
 begin
 god:=copy(formatdatetime('yyyy',(DateTimePicker1.Date)),1,4);
 data:=formatdatetime('ddmm',(DateTimePicker1.Date));
 mes:=formatdatetime('mm',(DateTimePicker1.Date));
 nf:='r00m00'+mes+god+'m70';
 data:=formatdatetime('ddmm',(DateTimePicker1.Date));
 text:='Delete from '+nf + ' where data='+''''+data+'''';
 FDQuery2.SQL.text:=text;
 FDQuery2.ExecSQL;
 ADOCommand1.CommandText:='pack table'+nf;
 ADOCommand1.Execute;
 end;
 end.
```

Comment: Я отстал от жизни, но совершенно не понимаю как команда вида `pack tabler00m00......m70`(смотрите внимательно что за команда уходит в ADO) должна запаковать вам БД, но думаю не тем путем идете товарищ! https://www.sql.ru/forum/292754/pakovat-dbf-bbase-iv-cherez-ado-iz-delphi-mozhno